# Расчет линии горизонта с core motion

Tags: ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте, ломаю голову над следующим:
Мне нужно иметь уровень горизонта на телефоне, чтобы он отображался линией или точной, но при вращении телефона (в любой плоскости) чтобы эта линия уходила либо наверх либо вниз. (Телефон в руках держим, либо портретная либо альбомная ориентация)

Для понимания: Возьмите карандаш горизонтально на уровне глаз и вращайте головой в любые стороны, линия карандаша (он же горизонт) будет смещаться либо вверх (если голову вниз клоним) и т.д. Вот нужно что то такое же сделать на iPhone. 
Яркий пример подобного это spirit level приложение в стандартном наборе iPhone (открываем компас и свайп влево делаем)

Я знаю как преобразовать чтобы линия например была всегда горизонтально, независимо от поворота телефона:

```
CMDeviceMotion *data;
double rotation = atan2(data.gravity.x, data.gravity.y) + M_PI;
self.myLineHoriz.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
```

Но как сделать чтобы от наклона телефона линия смещалась вверх либо вниз??

Нужно высчитать центр координат этой линии и менять его в зависимости от наклона. Уже несколько дней ломаю голову, но путних мыслей нет.

Answer (score 0):

Это комплексная задача на самом деле. Опишу всю проблематику:

1. Данные о наклоне девайса получаются от акселерометра. Это значит, что при собственное движение девайса будет влиять на его показания. Можно работать одновременно с акселерометром и гироскопом, то есть "откалибровать" гироскоп средними показаниями акселерометра и считать наклон девайса уже по гироскопу. Почти уверен, что такие алгоритмы уже написаны.
2. Камера находится в углу девайса, а не по его середине. То есть вращение девайса не вокруг камеры, а вокруг центра, как бы это сделал пользователь, создаст прецессию объектов, которую нужно корректировать. Но линия горизонта в данном случае - бесконечно удалённый объект, поэтому для неё проблем быть не должно
3. Камера имеет свой угол обзора - его нужно учитывать для того, чтобы определить насколько поворот девайса на 1 градус сместит линию горизонта горизонтально.
4. Камеры разных девайсов могут иметь разный угол обзора - это нужно будет установить опытным путём, а лучше - почитать в специцикации
5. Показания акселерометра использовать с учётом текущей ориентации интерфейса.
6. Раньше были популярны AR-view, которые показывали направление на объект в режиме камеры, лучшие из них я думаю должны были иметь решение всех описанных проблем. Типа таких https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit  https://github.com/calonso/ios-arkit